# Page not refreshed after confirmation Dilalog - JSF primefaces

Tags: jsf, web-applications, jsf-2

I am usinf JSF 2.0 and I have an XHTML page and this is the code :
-I have a  data table with a delete column that looks like this:

```
<p:column id="Delete" headerText="Delete">
<p:commandButton icon="delete" onclick="deleteConfirmation.show()" style="align:center">
<f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{item}" target="#{controller.selectedItem}" /> </p:commandButton>

</p:column>
```

- I have a Delete confirm dialog that looks like this :

  ```
  <p:commandButton id="confirm" value="Yes"
                      update=":myList" oncomplete="deleteConfirmation.hide()"
                      actionListener="#{controller.delete}" />
                  <p:commandButton id="cancel" value="No"
                      onclick="deleteConfirmation.hide()" type="button" />
  </p:confirmDialog>
  ```

everything works fine except that the confirmation button redirects to the page but the deleted Item still exists in the List if items. I think that the page is not refreshed after the Delete action because the item is deleted in the Database and it works fine.
Would you please help ?

Comment: I think your problem come from: You delete directly to database and not update datatable's list.

Comment: This seems a naming container problem. Can you post your whole page? Most important tags are here http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/NamingContainer.html

Comment: Your confirmation button does not do a redirect, it just updates the list. Did you try to update the whole form (update="@form")? If yes, what was the result - same problem? Another way is to do a real redirect. This will always work. (But also might do some stuff you don't want if you expect the behaviour of a 'normal' confirmation dialog)

Comment: I'm not sure, but as the delete dialog is probably within the same form as the table, isn't the colon before `:myList`making it point to a root item with id `myList`? What happens if you remove it? Another alternative would be to check the actual id of the table (look at the generated code in the browser) and specify the complete id (with colon); e.g. `:form_id:table_id`